# How to convert React-Native app to web version?

Tags: react-native

I have already completed a React-Native app. (And I used Firebase in app for backend.)
And there is 2 Figma files for both app & web version. How can I build web version in same style with web Figma design? App Figma and web Figma design are almost same.
How to convert it? I heard that "react-native-web" is useful for this. But all related blogs are videos are for creating app & web from scratch. I want to know how to convert pre-made React-Native app to web version. And after convert, can I reuse Firebase integration that has already used in app?
Anyone can explain the procedure step by step or send some links? Just hint will be also great appreciate.

Comment: You can try this, https://docs.expo.io/guides/running-in-the-browser/#adding-web-support-to-expo-projects

Comment: I am not using expo. Can it be done in react-native-cli ?

Comment: You can start using it now as bare workflow. https://docs.expo.io/bare/using-web/

Comment: Ok. thanks. Let me check once.